# HTML5 - are <p> and <h1> considered valid content for <nav>?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have a sidebar with latest news and random blog posts etc

```
<nav id="sidebar">
  <section id="latest_news">
    <h1>
      Latest News 
    </h1>
    <h2>
      <a href="/path/to/article">News Item 1</a>
    </h2> 
    <p>
      Truncated text from the news item in question
    </p>
    <a href="/news" title="View all news items" class="index">View all news items</a>
  </section>

  <section id="random_blog_post">
    <h1>
      Random Blog Post 
    </h1>
    <h2>
      <a href="/path/to/blog/post">Blog Post 1</a>
    </h2>
    <p>
      Truncated text from the random blog post in question
    </p>
    <a href="/blog" title="View all blog posts" class="index">View all blog posts</a>
  </section>
</nav>
```

As you can see, I've got sections, h1's and paragraphs inside my nav.

I'm just wondering if this allowed or considered good practice. Is there a better more semantic (or less) approach to marking-up and structuring such sidebar content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this appears to be pretty valid html5. w3org have an [example](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) of navigation with h1 tags in it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that, as also denoted in the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-nav-element)

Quotes specifically relevant to your question:

> The nav element represents a section
>   of a page that links to other pages or
>   to parts within the page: a section
>   with navigation links.

and

> A nav element doesn't have to contain a list, it can contain other kinds of content as well. In this navigation block, links are provided in prose:

```
 <nav>
 <h1>Navigation</h1>
 <p>You are on my home page. To the north lies <a href="/blog">my
 blog</a>, from whence the sounds of battle can be heard. To the east
 you can see a large mountain, upon which many <a
 href="/school">school papers</a> are littered. Far up thus mountain
 you can spy a little figure who appears to be me, desperately
 scribbling a <a href="/school/thesis">thesis</a>.</p>
 <p>To the west are several exits. One fun-looking exit is labeled <a
 href="http://games.example.com/">"games"</a>. Another more
 boring-looking exit is labeled <a
 href="http://isp.example.net/">ISP™</a>.</p>
 <p>To the south lies a dark and dank <a href="/about">contacts
 page</a>. Cobwebs cover its disused entrance, and at one point you
 see a rat run quickly out of the page.</p>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is just what i was hoping.  I have to give the accepted answer to @BadDisplayName because their post was 1 minute quicker than yours :) thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you could even write an h1 element as a direct child of the nav element so that the nav element would be named in the document's outline.

I suggest this reading about the importance of headings and document's outline:
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/headings-and-sections.html#outline

You can check your document's outline with this on-line tool:
http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/

Regards.